# Seeding data in IPAD application

Tags: ios, ipad

I am porting a desktop application to IPAD which is data centeric application. I have to move all the data which we already have in desktop version.

I have 3 tables and approx 5000+ rows.

How shold I create these 3 table and add rows to IOS application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to use SQLite for the database on the client, you could simply load all the data into the file and deliver it as a resource.  If you are looking for a SQLite GUI, there are a few in the app store, and some open source.  I use [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_sqlite/sqlite_overview.html) sometimes, the command line the rest of the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CoreData and iCloud, Apple recommends that you save all the records through the standard methods and not import a pre-filled DB. You can just run through a script on first launch  in the background, then popup a quick "Importing data... This will only happen once" message.